# CSS selector with OR condition

Tags: css

I am trying to select two selectors present in two different pages and I would like them to be applied if when the selector is detected (home page OR room page). I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

`body: not (.home), body: not (.single-room) .gdlr-core-privacy-box-wrap.gdlr-core-pos-bottom-bar {bottom: 90px;}`

Comment: `body:not(.home)` no spaces between the colon and not and the paranthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description i understand that you are trying to select the `.gdlr-core-privacy-box-wrap.gdlr-core-pos-bottom-bar` element both when the body has the class `home` or it has the class `single-room`. For that i think something like this would work:

````css
body:is(.home, .single-room) .gdlr-core-privacy-box-wrap.gdlr-core-pos-bottom-bar {
    bottom: 90px
}```
````